# Shape of a Large Battle Laser?

Tags: science-fiction, weapons, hard-science, lasers

If I have lasers being used as a primary weapon for spaceships in a realistic sci-fi setting, what would the proportions of the laser cannon itself be?  Presumably the cannon would be cylindrical, but I don't know enough about how lasers are generated to know if as lasers are scaled up, the cylinder would become proportionately longer and narrower, shorter and wider, or stay about the same.  Modern combat lasers, like those being tested by the US Navy:

[image]

Look to be about man-sized, and about four times longer than they are wide.  If I were to scale a laser up to the point where the lens was about 100 meters across, about how long would it be?

Comment: In reality, most lasers are round more because of the lenses than the actual laser, diode lasers are by far the most efficient (>60%) and are stupidly tiny. Here's an article about an 0.8 megawatt array from [Lawrence Livermore National Laboratories](https://www.laserfocusworld.com/lasers-sources/article/16551685/laser-pump-sources-four-800-kw-laserdiode-arrays-to-pump-highpulserate-hapls-petawatt-laser), it looks about the size of a desktop PC (holes on the bench are 1 inch apart). So, if you built a 100m x 100m (hectare) array, it'd be less than a meter thick and it'd pump out 170 GIGAWATTS!

Comment: You'd still have to a) power it, and b) deal with cooling it, but a phased laser array is definitely the most likely way to build an efficient laser weapon.

Answer (score 5):

## Frame Challenge: Bigger Ain't Better

Why would you want a lens 100m across?  Lasers are more capable of delivering power over distance the *narrower* their beam is.  More importantly, anti-ship weapons wouldn't *have* lenses; nothing is sufficiently optically pure to allow the laser energy to pass through without destroying the lens.

You want as small a beam as possible with as much energy as possible, so a really effective anti-ship weapon would be *cm* across, not meters.

Your problem would be less one of scale, and more one of managing ridiculous quantities of energy before expelling them at your target.  The goal is [Atomic Rockets'](http://www.projectrho.com/) [Ravening Beam of Death](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacegunconvent.php):

> Let's take a 10 MW ERC pumped FEL at just above the lead K-edge. This particular wavelength is used because lead is pretty much the heaviest non-radioactive element you can get, and at just above the highest core level absorption for a material you can get total external reflection at grazing angles - so no absorption or heating of a lead grazing incidence mirror. We will use a 1 meter diameter mirror. The Pb K-edge x-ray transition radiates at 1.4E-11 m. This gives us a divergence angle of 1.4E-11 radians. At 1 light second, we get a spot size of 5 mm, and an intensity of 5E11 W/m2.

> Looking at the NIST table of x-ray attenuation coefficients, and noting that 1.4E-11 m is a 88 keV photon, we find an attenuation coefficient of about 0.5 cm2/g for iron (we'll use this for steel), 0.15 cm2/g for graphite (we'll use this for high tech carbon materials) and 0.18 cm2/g for borosilicate glass (a very rough approximation for ceramics). Since graphite has a density of 1.7 g/cm3, we get a 1/e falloff distance (attenuation length) of 4 cm. Iron, with a density of 7.9 g/cm3, has an attenuation length of 0.25 cm. Glass, density 2.2 g/cm3, has an attenuation length of 2.5 cm.

> At 1 light second, therefore, the beam is depositing 2E12 W/cm3 in iron at the surface and 7E11 W/cm3 at 0.25 cm depth; 1.2E11 W/cm3 in graphite at the surface and 5E10 W/cm3 at 4 cm depth; and 2E11 W/cm3 in glass at the surface and 7E10 W/cm3 at 2.5 cm depth. Using 6E4 J/cm3 to vaporize iron initially at 300 K, we find that iron flashes to vapor within a microsecond to a depth of 0.9 cm. The glass, assumed to take 4.5E4 J/cm3 to vaporize (roughly appropriate for quartz) will flash to vapor within a microsecond to a depth of 4 cm within a microsecond. Graphite, at 1E5 J/cm3 for vaporization, will flash to vapor to a depth of 0.7 cm within a microsecond (the laser performs better if we let it dwell on graphite for a bit longer, we get a vaporization depth of 10 cm after ten microseconds).

> Net conclusion - ravening death beam at one light second.

> Now lets look at one light minute. The beam is now 30 cm across. This is much deeper than the attenuation length in all cases, so we will just find the radiant intensity and the equilibrium black body temperature of that intensity. We have an area of 7E-2 m2, and an intensity of 1.4E8 W/m2. You need to reach 7000 K before the irradiated surface is radiating as much energy away as heat as it is receiving as coherent x-rays. The boiling point of iron is 3023 K, the boiling point of quartz is 2503 K, and the sublimation temperature of graphite is 3640 K. All of these will be vaporized long before they stop gaining heat. At this range, the iron is subject to 5.6E8 W/cm3 at the surface, the graphite to 3.3E7 W/cm3 at the surface, and the glass to 5.6E7 W/cm3 at the surface. Using the above values for energy of vaporization, we get about 0.1 milliseconds before the iron starts to vaporize, 0.8 milliseconds before the glass starts to vaporize, and 3 milliseconds before the graphite begins to vaporize (because of its long attenuation length, once it begins to sublimate, graphite sublimates rapidly to a deep depth, while you essentially have to remove the iron layer by layer).

> Net conclusion - still a ravening death beam at one light minute.

In summary, you wouldn't be widening the aperture, you'd be improving the *optics* and optical cavity to handle higher and higher energies, but keeping the actual emitter as small as engineering allows.  The laser wouldn't get appreciably longer, but the energy systems would get *bigger*, presumably in pretty much all directions, to deal with energy flows and, importantly, *cooling*.

---

Edit: Adding a resource for laser materials' damage, in a general sense, to illustrate what was going on in the comments: [Laser Induced Damage](https://www.rp-photonics.com/laser_induced_damage.html).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118240/discussion-on-answer-by-jdunlop-shape-of-a-large-battle-laser).

Answer (score 1):

**Each would be a giant diamond crystal.**

[image: diamond laser]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiAtCLHFep8

You have a lot of little laser pump beams.  They combine their energy through a diamond and emit one giant beam, Death Star style. Little pump beams might escape out the side so give this things some space when you fire.   You get your enormous diamonds from the correct atmospheric level of a gas giant, where you can find them bobbing around.  You have a team of Ugnaughts to carve each into shape.  You carry a supply of spares.

Instead of a bunch of phallic protrusions from your ship (not that there is anything wrong with that) you have refracting giant diamonds, which your CGIsmiths make reflect and refract the ship next to it as well as the flashes of light from the space battle.  Your ship looks like a crown studded with jewels.  If that has been done I have not seen it.

Comment: This is the coolest thing I've seen all week. If somebody would use this in a movie I'd definitely go see it in theaters.

Answer (score 1):

No, no cylinders. The most optimal path is to hid your laser-generating part of the setup in the hull, leaving outside only a rotational mirror turret. Like that:

[image]

Do away with the useless in space aerodynamic shell, and you're left with this:

[image]

(The flaps are for the protection of the mirror from micrometeorites or the enemy and are closed in any instance the turret isn't lasing at a target)